# Tabs have full width

Tags: jquery-ui

Here is the undesired result I'm getting:
[Click for image (can't embed yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxMIs.png)

Note how the tabs instead of being next to each other all stretch to 100% width and are lined up like a list.

The HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $("#tabs").tabs();
```

Jquery version: 1.11.0.

Jquery-ui version: 1.10.4.

CSS is the jquery-ui.css you get by downloading 1.10.4 from the official site.

Here is [the link](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Arial%2CHelvetica%2Csans-serif&fsDefault=1.4em&fwDefault=normal&cornerRadius=0px&bgColorHeader=%23868A8D&bgTextureHeader=highlight_soft&borderColorHeader=%23868A8D&fcHeader=%23ffffff&iconColorHeader=%23ffffff&bgColorContent=%23586671&bgTextureContent=flat&borderColorContent=%23dedede&fcContent=%23ffffff&iconColorContent=%23222222&bgColorDefault=%23868A8D&bgTextureDefault=flat&borderColorDefault=%23868A8D&fcDefault=%23ffffff&iconColorDefault=%23666&bgColorHover=%2334383d&bgTextureHover=highlight_soft&borderColorHover=%23777D81&fcHover=%23ffffff&iconColorHover=%23ffffff&bgColorActive=%23124374&bgTextureActive=highlight_soft&borderColorActive=%23ffffff&fcActive=%23ffffff&iconColorActive=%23ffffff&bgColorHighlight=%23ffffff&bgTextureHighlight=glass&borderColorHighlight=%23ffffff&fcHighlight=%23000000&iconColorHighlight=%23000000&bgColorError=%23fef1ec&bgTextureError=glass&borderColorError=%23cd0a0a&fcError=%23cd0a0a&iconColorError=%23cd0a0a&bgColorOverlay=%23bbb9b9&bgTextureOverlay=flat&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=%23aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=flat&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=8px&offsetTopShadow=-8px&offsetLeftShadow=-8px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px&bgImgOpacityHeader=75&bgImgOpacityContent=75&bgImgOpacityDefault=75&bgImgOpacityHover=75&bgImgOpacityActive=65&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&bgImgOpacityError=95) to my ThemeRoller just in case (though I've tried with default theme also, to no avail).

I've tried upgrading / downgrading, disabled any other css I have on the page - But I just can' get the tabs to look OK even with no edits or custom code (I've changed some colors but it was done using official jquery-ui ThemeRoller).

Comment: have a look in the console for any other css that applies to the same items.

Comment: Was a silly programmer oversight (see my answer). Thanks for trying to help either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops!!!! When downloading the theme from the jquery ui site, I just noticed the components were toggled off! Hence no .css for the Tabs component.

One of those moments...

And something to be aware of for others.

(I will accept this as answer but I have to wait 2 days. As a famous Austrian once said: I'll be back. -- I have now accepted the answer).